# matplotlib does not plot the last data point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following code to plot my data. However, matplotlib does not plot the last data point.

First code gathers the data from the folder using `loadtxt`. After that I try to plot the data using:

`plt.plot(datalistx, datalisty)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os 
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
import numpy as np

NumS=20+1;



ydata=[]
folder_names = []
for entry_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    entry_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, entry_name)
    if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        folder_names.append(entry_name)
        ##print (entry_name)
        ydata.append(round(float(entry_name), 3))

xdata=[]
folder_paths = []
for entry_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    entry_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, entry_name)
    if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        folder_paths.append(entry_path)
        ##print  (entry_path)
        ##print  (entry_path+'\Drifts')
        path1=entry_path+"/"+"x."+"txt"
        path2=entry_path+"/"+"y."+"txt"
        datalistx = np.loadtxt(path1)
        datalisty = np.loadtxt(path2)
        plt.plot(datalistx,datalisty)
        plt.xlim(0, 0.045)

plt.xlabel('Maximum Interstory Drift')
plt.ylabel('Sa(T1) (g)')
#plt.legend();
plt.savefig("20str",dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does the quantity of `len(os.listdir(MYDIR))` match the quantity of drawing?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "last data point".  The last file in MYDIR?  The last data point in each `datalistx`/`datalisty`?    We can't really help w/o a minimal example .

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables - `datalistx`/`datalisty`. OR maybe you shouldn't use `plt.xlim(0, 0.045)`

Comment: BTW: it is more readable - `path1 = entry_path + "/x.txt"` but safer can be `path1 = os.path.join(entry_path, "x.txt")`